# Mapping over Either's Left

Tags: haskell, either

Somewhere in my app I receive an `Either ParserError MyParseResult` from Parsec. Downstream this result gets some other parsing done over using other libs. During that second phase of parsing there also may occur some kind of error which I would like to pass as a `Left String`, but for that I need to convert the result from Parsec to `String` too. To achieve that I need a function which will allow me to map over a `Left` with a `show` function.

The mapping function I'm thinking of looks something like this:

```
mapLeft :: (a -> b) -> Either a c -> Either b c
mapLeft f (Left x) = Left $ f x
mapLeft _ x = x
```

But I was quite surprised not to find anything matching on hackage db. So now I'm having doubts whether I'm using a correct approach to my problem.

Why isn't there such a function in standard lib? What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: You can't use `mapLeft _ x = x`, that must be `mapLeft _ (Right x) = Right x`, the argument and result have different types.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We have such a function in the standard libraries,

```
Control.Arrow.left :: a b c -> a (Either b d) (Either c d)
```

is the generalisation to arbitrary Arrows. Substitute `(->)` for `a` and apply it infix, to get the specialisation

```
left :: (b -> c) -> Either b d -> Either c d
```

There is nothing wrong with your approach in principle, it's a sensible way to handle the situation.

Comment: Oh. I'm not surprised I didn't even suspect it of being what I needed.  My mind wasn't ready to see the arrow as a type ) Thanks for opening my eyes!

Comment: `lens` also provides this function, by the name `over traverseLeft`.

Comment: It is `over _left` in recent versions -- in case someone comes across this later.

Answer (score 24):

Another option is to use [`Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) instance of `Either`. Then you have

```
first :: (a -> b) -> Either a c -> Either b c
```

(Also `Bifunctor` can be used to traverse over the first part of `(a,b)`.)

Comment: Seeing `Either` as a `Bifunctor` in a context that, as stated, what I needed was to "map", seems very reasonable. Thank you! I wonder why Hoogle doesn't include any of these functions in its results.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I was curious about that too, and I found out that [Hoogle searches: array, arrows, base, bytestring, Cabal, cgi, containers, directory, filepath, haskell-src, HUnit, mtl, old-locale, old-time, packedstring, parallel, parsec, pretty, process, QuickCheck, random, stm, template-haskell, time, xhtml](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hoogle#Scope_of_Web_Searches). Probably one would have to create a full, local database to search all Hackage libraries.

Answer (score 14):

This can be done easily with [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens):

```
import Control.Lens

over _Left (+1) $ Left 10   => Left 11
over _Left (+1) $ Right 10  => Right 10
over _Right (+1) $ Right 10 => Right 11
```

Comment: were `_Left` and `_Right` spelled with lower `l` and `r` in 2012?

Comment: According to the current documentation, they are `_Left` and `_Right`.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple option is `mapLeft` in `Data.Either.Combinators`:

```
mapLeft :: (a -> c) -> Either a b -> Either c b
```