# Catching exceptions in Scotty / Haskell

Tags: haskell, scotty

I'm just starting out learning Haskell and am stuck on how to handle exceptions in Scotty.

I have the basic function below. It gets a JSON POST, converts it in to a Haskell data record, gets a hold of a postgres connection pool from the config reader and then inserts the record in to the database.

```
create :: ActionT Text ConfigM ()
create = do
    a :: Affiliate <- jsonData
    pool  <- lift $ asks pool
    _ <- liftIO $ catchViolation catcher $ withResource pool $ \conn ->
        PgSQL.execute conn "INSERT INTO affiliate (id, network, name, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
            (slug a, network a, name a, status a)
    let s = fromStrict $ unSlug $ slug a
    text $ "Created: " `T.append` s
where
    catcher e (UniqueViolation "mykey") = throw e --text "Error"
    catcher e _ = throw e
```

This function compiles ok but when I change the UniqueViolation to return text it fails to compile.

```
catcher e (UniqueViolation "mykey") = text "Error"
```

The compilation error given is:

```
Couldn't match type ‘ActionT e0 m0 ()’ with ‘IO Int64’
    Expected type: PgSQL.SqlError -> ConstraintViolation -> IO Int64
      Actual type: PgSQL.SqlError
               -> ConstraintViolation -> ActionT e0 m0 ()
In the first argument of ‘catchViolation’, namely ‘catcher’
In the expression: catchViolation catcher
```

*catchViolation* comes from the [Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.Errors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-Errors.html) and has the below signiture:

```
catchViolation :: (SqlError -> ConstraintViolation -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a
```

I know part of the issue is it's getting the IO Int64 from PgSQL.execute but a ActionT from the catcher but not sure how to resolve the types or a more idiomatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the return value of `catchViolation` lives in the `IO` monad, but `text` lives in the  `ActionT e IO` monad, which is a monad built on top on `IO` using the `ActionT` monad transformer.

Monad transformers add additional capabilities to their base monads. In the case of `ActionT`, it adds things like access to the "response-in-construction" (which is why `text` requires it).

One possible solution is to pull the use of `text` out of `catchViolation`. Instead, make `catchViolation` return an `Either`, and then, once back into an `ActionT` context, pattern match on the `Either` to decide what to do. Something like:

```
ei <- liftIO $ catchViolation catcher $ fmap Right $ withResource pool
case ei of
    Left str -> text str
    Right _ -> return ()
where 
    catcher e (UniqueViolation "mykey") = return $ Left "some error"
    catcher e _ = return $ Left "some other error"
```

There's another solution, more powerful but not as intuitive. It happens that [`ActionT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.9.1/docs/Web-Scotty-Trans.html#t:ActionT) is an instance of  [`MonadBaseControl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl). This typeclass has [methods](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#v:liftBaseWith) that let you hide all the "extra layers" added by monad transformers into a plain value of the base monad. You can then pass that value to some callback-accepting function like `catchViolation`, and afterwards "pop out" all the extra layers back.

(It's a bit like pressing a jack-in-the-box back into its box in order to pass through customs or whatever, and then making it spring out again.)

It would be something like:

```
control $ \runInBase -> catchViolation 
     (\_ _ -> runInBase $ text "some error") 
     (runInBase $ liftIO $ withResource $ 
                .... all the query stuff goes here ...)
```

We are using the [control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#v:control) utility function. `control` provides you with a magical function (`RunInBase m b`) that lets you "put the jack-in-the-box back into the box". That is, construct an `IO` value out of an `ActionT` one. You then pass that value to `catchViolation`, and `control` takes care of unpaking the layers encoded in the result, bringing back the full `ActionT` monad at the end.

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right lines with Either and the types.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you put me on the right lines with the [Either](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.52.0/docs/Control-Monad-Either.html). I found *try* in [Control.Exception](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:try) which creates an Either from an IO of a:

```
try :: Exception e => IO a -> IO (Either e a)
```

I use try to give me an *[Either SqlError Int64]* from the PostgreSQL Simple execute function then do a map on the left values with the PostgreSQL Simple [constraintViolation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-Errors.html) function using [Control.Arrow.left](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Arrow.html) which I found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13504032/2658199.

```
constraintViolation :: SqlError -> Maybe ConstraintViolation

left :: a b c -> a (Either b d) (Either c d)
```

This then gives me the below type to pattern match on

```
Either (Maybe ConstraintViolation) Int64
```

With the above I've come up with the this which I'm happy with but not sure if idiomatic or can be further improved?

```
create' :: ActionT Text ConfigM ()
create' = do
  a :: Affiliate <- jsonData
  pool  <- lift $ asks pool
  result <- liftIO $ E.try $ withResource pool $ \conn -> do
       PgSQL.execute conn "INSERT INTO affiliate (id, network, name, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
                (slug a, network a, name a, status a)
  let slugT = fromStrict $ unSlug $ slug a
  case left constraintViolation result of
    Right _ -> text $ "Created: " `T.append` slugT
    Left(Just(UniqueViolation "mykey")) -> text "Duplicate key"
    _ -> text "Fatal Error"
```

### Update

After the suggestion of using `ViewPatterns` I've simplified my previous version to the below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, ScopedTypeVariables, ViewPatterns #-}

create :: ActionT Text ConfigM ()
create = do
    a :: A.Affiliate <- jsonData
    pool  <- lift $ asks pool
    result <- liftIO $ try $ withResource pool $ \conn ->
        PgSQL.execute conn "INSERT INTO affiliate (id, network, name, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
          (A.slug a, A.network a, A.name a, A.status a)
    let slugT = fromStrict $ unSlug $ A.slug a
    case result of
        Right _ -> text ("Created: " `T.append` slugT) >> status created201
        Left (constraintViolation -> Just (UniqueViolation _)) -> text (slugT `T.append` " already exists") >> status badRequest400
        Left e -> throw e
```

Comment: When pattern-matching, leave a space after the constructor: `Left (Just (...`. To manipulate the two branches of an `Either`, you can also use the `Bifunctor` typeclass from `Data.Bifunctor`. You could also use the `ViewPatterns` extension, that would let you do things like `Left (constraintViolation -> Just (UniqueViolation "mykey")) -> ...` https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-02-view-patterns.html

Comment: One thing: when working in the `IO` monad, or in a monad based on `IO`, it's better to use `throwIO` instead of `throw` (lifting it with `liftIO` as needed). `throw` is better left for pure code.